# Active X error blocking code

Tags: javascript, html, css, iframe, activex

My code works in Firefox but breaks in Chrome. It only happens when I include embedded iframes or embed objects.

In IE I receive a message about Active X blocking content on the page.

I click allow content and the code works, otherwise it breaks in IE as well.

what can be causing this error? I've read that HTML elements can't overlap Active X elements. I have iframe but also a docked (fixed position on scroll) header and a fixed positioned nav bar on the right of the screen that are supposed to stay on top of all elements, but adding embedded content makes these sticky divs disappear.

Is this the problem? Is there a workaround?

Comment: What ActiveX component are you using?

Comment: I don't know anything about ActiveX. That is just the message I received :\

Comment: Could you post a link where I can check it out?

Comment: Here is a  [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/F9y7V/) that I used to recreate the code and the problem, but apparently it only works (recreates the issue) sometimes and works fine others. But it uses the same concept (embeds with fixed divs) that my code uses (which isn't published yet)

Answer (score 0):

I've taken a look at your fiddle and I've found a solution;
What you need to do is give your titlebar a z-index. If you don't specify a z-index in the css the browser will order elements in the order they appear in your DOM tree.
Also I noticed your menu wasn't closed correctly.
You can see what I did here:

```
    .title{
            width:100%;
            font-size:200%;
            background-color:#0C2C52;/*Alternative: #6D929B */
            opacity:.9;
            color: white;
            text-align: center;
            font-family: "Lucida Grande", "Lucida Sans Unicode", "Lucida Sans", Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
            border-radius: 2px;
            z-index:999;
        }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/F9y7V/8/

Comment: Thanks for this answer, but it did not work for me. Also, I think I read somewhere in my endless pursuit to solve this that z-index does not affect iframes or embeds..

Comment: I don't think that's true as the fiddle shows the iframe under the titlebar in my browser. What browser are you using?  
You could also try using an object instead of iframe and setting the WMODE param to transparent, although I believe that is only for flash.

Comment: I'm using Chrome. I've given up on trying to solve this. There seems to be no resolution for me, and it's too stressful. I've just left the media out of my page which doesn't make it nearly as cool as I planned it but I give up. But thanks a lot for your help.